# ToDo every second

Tags: android, button, timer

Here is my code:

```
Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);
Button Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Working..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        InputString = Input.getText().toString();
        InputArr = InputString.split(" ");
        L=InputArr.length;
        while (L!=0)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),InputArr[L-1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            Output.setText(InputArr[L-1]);
            L--;
        }
    }
);
```

I want to set Output text to `InputArr[L-1]` every second, but when I run the application and click the button, I just see the `InputArr[1]` and not all the Process, why?

Comment: Use CountDownTimer instead of making thread sleep for 1 sec

Comment: how? i am new in android development..

i tried to do 

private final Handler handler = new Handler();
 button...while....

handler.postDelayed(3000, 1000);
Output.setText(InputArr[L-1]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go , but first see this [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Create another method where you will be adding the timer

```
private void xyz(String[] InputArr){
    int L=0;
    CountDownTimer cdt= new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Output.setText(InputArr[L]);
        L++;
      }

   }.start();


 }
```

And call this method inside the onClick method like this

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Working..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    InputString = Input.getText().toString();
    InputArr = InputString.split(" ");
    xyz(InputArr);
}
```